# How to get the text entered in an edittext?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I want to get the data entered in an `edittext` of android fragment in that same fragment of android.

I want that input details and send to a ble device.

**Code is here:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setCancelable(false);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.verification, null);
        verify=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.verify);
        Next =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        Cancel=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        Next.setOnClickListener(this);
        Cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        appContext = AppContext.getContext();
        mContext=getActivity();
        appContext = AppContext.getContext();
        mOnDataSendListener = appContext.getOnDataSendListener();

        timer();
        Time=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.next){
            factoryReset();
        }
        else {
            dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: send to where??

Comment: send that input to a ble device.i just want to rdetrieve the data first

Comment: do you mean to get the text ? `verify.getText().toString()`

Comment: I answered your . Is it as your requirement , Please reply @subhashreesahoo

Answer (score 0):

Get `verify` data when you call method `factoryReset()` & send data as a parameter. Use below line to `getText` from `editText`:

```
verify.getText().toString()
```

Try with below code :

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId()==R.id.next){
        factoryReset(verify.getText().toString());
    }
    else {
        dismiss();
    }


public void factoryReset(String str1){
 Log.e("VERIFY_DATA",""+str1);
}
```